# NEW Apple Magic Keyboard: F1 to F12 keys do not work, cannot adjust brightness, sound volume, etc

Tags: keyboard, imac

I use iMac (27-inch, Late 2012) running on Catalina 10.15.7 (19H1715). Just bought a new Apple Magic Keyboard with Touch ID. The problem I have is that NONE of the buttons inside the red rectangle (see photo) work. The result is that I cannot increase/decrease brightness; skip songs; increase/decrease volumes, etc. I did not have this problem on my old magic keyboard.

Does anyone have any solutions, please?

Hardware Overview:

- Model Name:   iMac
- Model Identifier: iMac 13,2
- Processor Name:   Quad-Core Intel Core i7
- Processor Speed:  3.4 GHz
- Number of Processors: 1
- Total Number of Cores:    4
- L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
- L3 Cache: 8 MB
- Hyper-Threading Technology:   Enabled
- Memory:   32 GB
- Boot ROM Version: 425.0.0.0.0

[image]

Comment: there is no photo attached.

Comment: Look at System Prefs > Keyboard > "Use F1, F2 etc as standard function keys"

Answer (score 2):

In case you haven't thought of it, go into **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** with the keyboard attached and make sure **Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys** is ***not*** checked. If this is the problem, then holding the <kbd>Fn</kbd> (bottom-left) and <kbd>F12</kbd> would work to increase the volume but not <kbd>F12</kbd> by itself.

macOS keeps these settings on a per-keyboard basis, so perhaps somehow it got toggled for the new keyboard you connected.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the magic keyboard 2 on iMac (late 2013) High Sierra 10.13.6. It is as though these buttons do not exist and are not recognised. The only thing that worked was installing Karabiner-Elements app.
https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/
You can download the version that corresponds to your operating system.
[image: Karabiner-Elements: Select correct version for download]

Answer (score 1):

The only think that worked for me was forgetting the keyboard in  bluetooth settings, and pairing it again. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Simple as that, yeah.